# sharepoint 2013 - text tool bar

Tags: sharepoint-server, word, rich-text

I have a problem copying text from various word documents into a SharePoint rich text field. For example, when I copy in text, additional tags are included which adds a new line in the SharePoint text field.

I cannot copy into the field with clear formatting as we have bold and underline text. Any ideas or is there a third party plug in for SharePoint that provides the ability to clean the code of certain html tags?

regards 
Kevin

Comment: Did you help my answer? Mark it please.

Answer (score 0):

This Copy/Past from Word with formatting never works correctly. Working with rich text is that you are formatting inside of it, not that you are insering in.

You can:

- Copy it directly from Word and after it edit in SharePoint Text Editor.
- Copy text to Notepad, it will remove the formatting from Word and after this copy clear text from Notepad to SharePoint Text Field.